# Python string cent symbol conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

The string I have is

```
u'3.4\xa2 / each'
```

The `'\xa2'` is the "cent" symbol, and I want to show it that way.

I tried

```
i= "3.4\xa2 / each"
print unicode(i, errors='replace')
```

In the result, the cent symbol is shown as a question mark inside a solid circle.

I also tried

```
i= "3.4\xa2 / each"
print i.encode('utf-8')
```

I get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So what is the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: What operating system are you using? On Ubuntu 14.04, `print  u'3.4\xa2 / each'` correctly displays `3.4¢ / each`/

Comment: @Robᵩ: ah, but you created a unicode string literal. That little `u` at the start..

Comment: So did OP, on line 1 of the question.

Comment: Ah, but not in the second code snippet. I wonder which he actually has?

Comment: @Robᵩ; good question, but given that the `encode` failed the way it did, it is not a Unicode string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'\xa2'` is a *byte*. It **may** be interpreted as a cent symbol, but only if you specify the right codec. By specifying the right codec can you decode it to the Unicode codepoint equivalent. Latin-1 would do:

```
>>> print '\xa2'.decode('latin1')
¢
```

There are a whole [series of encodings](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a2/charset_support.htm) that encode the `¢` cent codepoint as A2, however.

Alternatively, start with a Unicode string to begin with. `\xa2` in a Unicode string expression is the same thing as `\u00a2`, which happens to be the right codepoint:

```
>>> print u'\xa2'
¢
>>> print u'\u00a2'
¢
```

That's because the first 256 codepoints of the Unicode standard happen to match the Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) standard.

You may have trouble printing; if you are using a terminal or console, `print` is supposed to automatically encode Unicode data to match your terminal or console configuration, but that may not always be correct or be set to a codec that can handle the characters you are trying to print!

Note that I *decoded*. If you *encode*, Python tries to be helpful and decode the bytes to a Unicode object first, so that it can be encoded afterwards. Because `\xa2` in not a valid ASCII byte, that decoding failed.

You may want to read:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

- `encode` is a method to convert unicode strings to bytes. If you call `encode` on a byte string, Python2 will first try to decode it with ASCII and then encode it. That's where your error is coming from.
- Your string cannot be decoded with UTF-8, because not every sequence of bytes is valid UTF-8.

Demo:

```
>>> "3.4\xa2 / each".decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

- You can use the latin-1 encoding here, because it maps every byte to the corresponding unicode ordinal.

Demo:

```
>>> print("3.4\xa2 / each".decode('latin-1'))
3.4¢ / each
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
 print "3.4" + u"\u00A2" +"each"
```

Works for me.

Comment: You don't want to rely on implicit conversions. Use a Unicode string for the whole expression. Also, you can't use `print` and assignment statements on the same line.

Comment: You didn't add any spaces either. Why not just use `u'3.4\u00A2 each'`? And you may want to *explain* why what you tried works.